# rtmpdump options confused between -p and -r

Tags: vlc, rtmp, rtmps

Does anyone know the difference between the `-p` and the `-r`options in the `rtmpdump` utility for media streaming? I am confused because I think that the RTMP server should be the server streaming the video, but then `rtmpdump` asks for the `-p` option, which is the page url...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it:

`-r` (or `--rtmp`) is for specifying the actual location of the content stream/server.

`-p` (or `--pageUrl`) is for the URL of the website where the SWF player (which is the `-W` or `--swfUrl` argument) was embedded.

So, if you would ordinarily find your stream by going to `http://example.com/video`, that would go under `-p`. The flash *player* embedded on or accessed from that page would go under `-W`. The server that the flash player streams the content from belongs to `-r`.

See `man rtmpdump` or `rtmpdump --help` for all the options.